# Eager loading returning null

Tags: laravel-4

I have 2 models:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Question');
    }
}

class Question extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

In my questions controller, I have the following function:

```
public function index()
    {
        $questions =  Question::with('users')->get();
        return View::make('questions.index')->with('questions', $questions);
    }
```

But when accessing this route, I get the following error:

```
'Trying to get property of non-object ...'
```

However, if I add the foreign key to the questions model like so:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }
```

Then everything works fine.

The thing is, I thought you only had to add the foreign key as the second parameter if it didn't follow the convention of using the model name followed by _id, which I did.

I know It works fine now but I'd like to know why I had to add the foreign key as the second parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe it tries to use the model's capitalized name, `User_id` instead of `user_id` ?

Comment: Is your database user table column 'id' or 'user_id'?